# React Native Android app 0.63.3 crashing in release after upgrading gradle from 4.0.1 to 4.2.2

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am experiencing android build failures in AppCenter due to the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase_messaging:generateReleaseRFile'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > /Users/runner/work/1/s/HeliaConnect/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android/build/intermediates/symbol_list_with_package_name/release/package-aware-r.txt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

It appears that AppCenter has recently depreciated a bunch of supported decencies. But I am having trouble figuring out the best next steps to resolve the failed builds.

Current Versions:

- React Native 0.63.3
- Gradle: 6.2
- Android Gradle Plugin: 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting successful android builds by bumping `gradle` and `android gradle plugin` versions:

```
       - classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
```

```
     - distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip
       distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9.2-bin.zip
```

However, even with the successful build, I was then experiencing release version app crashes upon opening the app with the following error:

```
06-23 23:48:31.662 E/AndroidRuntime( 7875): FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
06-23 23:48:31.662 E/AndroidRuntime( 7875): Process: com.heliaconnect.qa, PID: 7875
06-23 23:48:31.662 E/AndroidRuntime( 7875): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release
```

After, a a bit of digging, it appears that react native 0.63.3 is not compatible with android gradle plugin 4.1+/ gradle 6.5+. Here is the relevant react native [changelogs](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0634) bullet for the 0.63.4 version changelogs:

```
Fix App Bundle/Release build missing index.android.bundle with gradle plugin 4.1.0/gradle 6.5 (53f55001af by @tomoima525)
```

After bumping react native to 0.64.4, the release version of the app no longer crashed upon open!

I hope this helps someone.